# Django: Vacate unique name if field is a particular value

Tags: python, django, django-models

**What I want**

I want a field to be **unique** unless a other field in a the same model is a particular value. Allowing me to vacate this unique name to a future model instance.

I also need to allow `testname` to be `null` encase there is no `testname` for that given test.

*Unique Field*: `testname`

*Conditioner*: `cancelled=True`

**models.py *(Simplified)***

```py
class Test(models.Model):
    testname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    cancelled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`UniqueConstraint`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint):

```py
class Test(models.Model):
    testname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    cancelled = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        constraints = (
            UniqueConstraint(fields=['testname'], condition=Q(cancelled=True), name='...'),
        )
```

This will add a constraint in your database table, making conditional uniqueness of the field. In this case, the form validation is not supported out of the box, so you need to add it separately.